# Domain object validation with Play! framework

Tags: java, validation, playframework

I want to validate a domain object without automatic parameter binding to restrict the properties that can be set by the client.

The following class (example from [Play! docs](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/validation)) ...

```
public class User {

    @Required
    public String name;

    @Required
    @Min(0)
    public Integer age;
}
```

... is usually validated like this

```
public static void hello(@Valid User user) {
   if(validation.hasErrors()) {
       params.flash();
       validation.keep();
       index();
   }
   render(user);
}
```

But in this scenario all fields of `user` can be set by the client.

Is it possible to trigger domain object validation (not "controller validation") with Play! 1.2 explicitly?

```
public static void hello(long id, String name) {
   User user = User.findById(id);
   user.name = name;

   user.validate(); // <-- I miss something like this 

   if(validation.hasErrors()) {
       params.flash(); 
       validation.keep(); 
       index();
   }
   render(user);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried

```
validation.valid(user);
```

Comment: And what if, not being in an Action at all, "validation" is not instanciated?

Comment: nevermind, found it: the Validation object creator is protected, but there's a ".current()"...

Answer (score 1):

You can add the *@Required* to the *name* parameter and turn the code into:

```
public static void hello(long id, @Required String name) {
   if(validation.hasErrors()) {
       params.flash(); 
       validation.keep(); 
       index();
   } 
   User user = User.findById(id);
   user.name = name;
   render(user);
}
```

You can extend the annotation to *@Required(message="key.to.i18n.message")* for I18N purposes.